# Smooch Bot Working on Heroku Has No replying

Tags: heroku, bots, smooch

I am trying to make a chat-bot via [EstherBot](https://github.com/esthercrawford/EstherBot) with Smooch and Heroku.
Following the steps and setting without finding out any error, and finally it could launch on the heroku [here](https://jwcbot.herokuapp.com/) successfully; however, as I tried to chat with my bot, it replied nothing, not like EstherBot could say hello to every visitor.
Though Bot didn't reply something, I received the chatting content in my mailbox. This means Smooch has connected to heroku and my email.
Also, I can change settings on smooch like adding a whisper, and it works on my bot right away.
But, still is, the bot didn't reply me.
I am not sure where I went wrong. Could somebody help me point in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example#troubleshooting-your-bot

Comment: Hi, @AndrewLavers. I finally found that I didn't configure SERVICE_URL in heroku. Now it works! Thank you very much!